# Simplest way to find if an array ends with a subset

Tags: c#, algorithm

Let's say I have an array of ints: `[1, 2, 4, 9, 5, 6, 8, 7]`. I have a second array, `[8, 7, 6]`.  What I want to know is, does the first array end with the same values as the second array, not necessarily in the same order?  (In this case, the result should be `true`.)

Invariants that can be relied upon:

- `array1.Length > array2.Length`
- All elements in `array1` are unique.
- All elements in `array2` are unique.

What is the simplest way to answer this question?  It would be particularly nice if there was a reasonably efficient solution that does not require any allocations.

Comment: The most efficient would use a HashSet where you add the last n numbers from the first array then check that all the numbers in the second array are in the hash.  That would run in linear time.  Anything that doesn't do allocations would at best run in n log n as you'd need to sort the last n numbers of the first array and the entire second array and then compare.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a simple O(nlogn) complexity (n = size of array2) in this way:

- sort array2
- sort the last n elements of array1
- compare element-by-element array2 and the last n element of array1

This should be the best you can do without any additional allocation

Answer (score 0):

I think LINQ is the easiest way to do this:

```cs
using System.Linq;

bool EndsWithSubset(int[] array1, int[] array2)
{
    return array1
        .TakeLast(array2.Length)
        .ToHashSet()
        .SetEquals(array2);
}
```

Example usage:

```cs
Console.WriteLine(
    EndsWithSubset(
        new [] { 1, 2, 4, 9, 5, 6, 8, 7 },
        new [] { 8, 7, 6 }
    ));   // True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can *query* the arrays with a help of *Linq*. Here we exploit the fact that all values are *unique* (no duplicates):

```
 bool contains = !array1
                    .Skip(array1.Length - array2.Length)
                    .Except(array2)
                    .Any();
```

Here we

1. Obtain `array1` *suffix* with a help of `.Skip(array.Length - array2.Length)`
2. Subtract `array2` with `.Except(array2)`
3. Then check if any items remain - `.Any()`

Answer (score 0):

If the 2nd array is usually not that long you just might sort both sequences and compare element wise. If it is long the cost for sorting is probably high and using a hashset would turn out more effective.

```
 bool endsEqual = arr1.TakeLast(arr2.Length)
                      .OrderBy(i => i)
                      .SequenceEqual(arr2.OrderBy(i => i));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use HashSet to do this:

```
    bool Func(int[] array1, int[] array2)
    {
        if (array1.Length < array2.Length)
            return false;
        return new HashSet<int>(array1.Skip(array1.Length - array2.Length)).SetEquals(new HashSet<int>(array2));
    }
```